# Forcing bootstrap carousel vertical on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the bootstrap carousel, I need to force the layout to be centered and scroll vertically on mobile. Not sure how to align the columns so that they stack vertically, with the carousel controls(arrows) set center at the top and bottom. Each set of 4 slides should appear at once, and on clicking the up or down arrows, all 4 should slide out of view, allowing the previous or following 4 to display.

**This is how it needs to look on mobile:**

[image]

The current implementation is setup like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="contain">
  <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

  <div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
    </div><!--.row-->
  </div><!--.item-->

  <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
    </div><!--.row-->
  </div><!--.item-->

  <div class="item">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a><p>Title text</p></div>
    </div><!--.row-->
  </div><!--.item-->

  </div><!--.carousel-inner-->
    <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
    <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
  </div><!--.Carousel-->
</div>
</div>
</div><!--.container-->
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-control {
    left: 11%;
      height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
      border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
      margin-top: 90px;
  }
  .carousel-control.right{
    left: 90%!important;
  }
  .carousel-inner{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .carousel-control.right {
    left: 86%!important;
  }
  /* The indicators */
  .carousel-indicators {
    display: none;
  }
```

**Current fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snytpsyr/1/**

Comment: at your row class you can use `text-align:center`. and you want to switch the carousel vertical to horizontal ?

Comment: The vertical scroll should look like the screenshot image in the question. The up and down arrows should be on top and bottom, and the slides should scroll vertically.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/mcuznz/bootstrap-carousel-vertical, which is allowing the slides to move vertically. Just need to set the carousel to only scroll vertically on mobile (and left/right on landscape) then fix the position of the arrows. I've updated my fiddle to reflect the current state.

Comment: @fsi - Ideas on how to set to only scroll vertically on mobile?

Comment: Someone briefly posted a working answer, but it's since been deleted. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This allows the carousel to scroll horizontally on landscape, and vertically on mobile, as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/joav6tee/1/

```
.carousel-control {
    left: 11%;
      height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
      border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
      margin-top: 90px;
  }
  .carousel-control.right{
    left: 90%!important;
  }
  .carousel-inner{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .carousel-control.right {
    left: 86%!important;
  }
  /* The indicators */
  .carousel-indicators {
    display: none;
  }
    .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel.vertical .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -moz-transition:    0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -ms-transition:     0.6s ease-in-out top;
  -o-transition:      0.6s ease-in-out top;
  left:               0;
}
.carousel.vertical .active,
.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right    { top:     0; }
.carousel.vertical .next,
.carousel.vertical .active.right  { top:  100%; }
.carousel.vertical .prev,
.carousel.vertical .active.left   { top: -100%; }

@media screen and (min-width:993px) {

.carousel.vertical .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out all;
  -moz-transition:    0.6s ease-in-out all;
  -ms-transition:     0.6s ease-in-out all;
  -o-transition:      0.6s ease-in-out all;
  right:               0;
}

  .carousel.vertical .active,
.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right    { top:     0; right:0;}
.carousel.vertical .next,
.carousel.vertical .active.right  { top:0;right:  -100%; }
.carousel.vertical .prev,
.carousel.vertical .active.left   { top:0;right: 100%; }
}
```